# Is it possible to change the event type of an event listener in Firebase during runtime?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example, I called a listener once with a .ChildAdded event type but later I want to call that same listener again with a .ChildRemoved listener.

```
func loadMe(r: Resource<MyResourceType>, withBlock: (MyResourceType?, FIRDataEventType) -> Void) {
    spinner?.startAnimating()
    r.RootRef.child(r.path).observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        withBlock(r.parse(snapshot.value as? FBDictionary, snapshot.key, r.path), .ChildAdded)
    }
    r.RootRef.child(r.path).observeEventType(.ChildRemoved) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        withBlock(r.parse(snapshot.value as? FBDictionary, snapshot.key, r.path), .ChildRemoved)
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your work in form of code

Answer (score 2):

Once created Firebase event listeners are immutable. So you cannot change the event type after registering one.